# Interactive line graph in iOS

Tags: objective-c, graph

I want to create interactive line graph which will change as user drag. I mean if there are 5 values, 5 points will there on graph. User should able to change the value by dragging points on graph which will change the lines on the graph. Lines should increase or decrease as user move the points.

Can you please suggest some open source library?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This question should be closed because:

*"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

However I'm leaving my original answer.

- https://www.shinobicontrols.com/ (not open source, but leader in this field)
- https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot
- https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts

There're tons of them. That's hardly a question and does not suggest any input(research) from your side, so I'm not sure if I'm doing any good to answer this question...?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I guess  you didn't read my question properly. I do not want static graphs. These frameworks I already checked. These frameworks gives static graphs.

Comment: @NuzhatZari What do you mean via static graphs? All of them (as far as I know) allow you to reload data points and move them by touch.